# Set environment variables with plink.exe

Tags: ssh, putty

Similar questions have been asked before, but I believe they do not cover my issue.
I want the set an environment variable, that changes dynamically, for an ssh session using Plink. Using Putty I can define this in the GUI:

[image]

When using plink.exe, I don't see an option to add environment variable. I can use plink to load a saved session, which will set the environment variable, but this will not work in my case (scripted).

Is there an option the set the environment variable on the plink commandline?

Comment: Is this the Windows implementation or a Linux one?

Comment: This is plink for Windows